# Is there way to transfer login data from index page to another pages?

Tags: php, html, authentication, session, registration

I've been working on this school project. It's project about Weather info web page. I've done 90% of project but i've been stuck on this part: I created index page with login and registration. Both login and registration have been connected to phpmyadmin/mysql and all works fine. After index.html user then goes to page where he will confirm he's data(data is pulled from mysql). Now problem is when i register new user, it always pulls data of last user in mysql table(eg. i log on with 1st user in table but i get data from last person in table), so i need something to "attach" to user who is logging in, so that page pulls his name and location, not from last user in table. I hope u will understand my problem. I've been using mostly PHP for retriving data then forwarding it to HTML to display data. [code of index page with login](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kj0Bo.png) 
[code of page where u get after login](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XJI6N.png)

Comment: alda998 - we need more from you. Describing the situation is helpful, but showing us with code is central. Creating a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) makes the difference between us all _imagining_ what you have done, or might have done, and _seeing_ it. If we can see it, clearly, and in a nice short form, we are more likely to work on an answer, which means you're more likely to get one!

Comment: @Yishmeray sorry, i added two pictures of my index page and page after u get after login. I hope that will help. Sorry again for not posting pics first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood right your question, you need a php [**$_SESSION**](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp). You can create $_SESSION after your login form (if successful). And you can check data of this $_SESSION at another PHP pages.

Example:

```
<?php
// Start the session (it must be in every PHP file, which you use $_SESSION)
session_start();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<?php
// Create session
$_SESSION["session_name"] = "test";
$_SESSION["user_id"] = 1;
$_SESSION["username"] = "test_user";

//In other php pages
//Check session and if exists, retrieve data
if(isset($_SESSION["user_id"])){
  $user_id = $_SESSION["user_id"];
}else{
  echo "There are not any logged user.";
}
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thank you for ur reply. Should i add session in same page where u type login or on next page?

Comment: It doesn't matter. You must create a session when you know your user logged succesful. For example, user wrote his username and password, and then click Submit button. Firstly, you must check the user datas in your database, if it's correct, then create a session and redirect user somewhere (home, my account page etc.).

Comment: yeah, i got validation.php where cheks user datas and if it's correct it headers it to main page. Should i put your code that u send me before header. Here is a picture of code https://prnt.sc/sc3tnt

Comment: You must create session. Here is example code: [https://codeshare.io/24Elzd](https://codeshare.io/24Elzd) .Remember: Dont keep passwords in the database as a plain text. Use md5(), sha256() etc.